# Is it strange/uncommon to use next when then should be used? (For example, when only two actions are occurring?)

Tags: sentence-construction, conjunctions

Usually, you would write: first ... next ... then ... finally.

When there are only two actions, you'd usually use "then":

> She inspected me with her eyes. **Then,** she brought a tiny hand to her chin and said, "I think I know you."

What if you use "next" in these type of situations? Is it strange/uncommon?

> She inspected me with her eyes. **Next,** she brought a tiny hand to her chin and said, "I think I know you."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the order of *then* and *next* in a list is very fluid (IMO there's no strict rule as to which goes first), *next* does usually have to be used in a formal list such as a list of instructions. For example:

> She inspected me with her eyes. Next, she brought a tiny hand to her chin and said, "I think I know you." Finally, she closed the eyes that had  previously being inspecting me.

Despite there bring three actions, this sounds unnatural because it is prose, but words like *next* and *finally* belong in a list of instructions or similar.

> She inspected me with her eyes. Then, she brought a tiny hand to her chin and said, "I think I know you." before closing the eyes that previously been inspecting me.

This sounds much more natural because words like *then* and *before* were used (which fit better into prose).

Note that *next* and *before* (and *and*) can still be used in formal lists, but not the other way around.